# Move mouse smoothly

Tags: c++, winapi, easing

I'm trying to move the user mouse using `mouse_event` function in WinAPI. This is my code:

```
    while (LeftMouseDown)
    {
        POINT cursorPos;
        GetCursorPos(&cursorPos);
        //X Axis And Y Axis is DWORD Array
        mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE, xaxis[iCount], yaxis[iCount], 0, 0);
        iCount++;
        Sleep(200);
    }
```

It's working good but the problem is that I want the code smooth movement, because the function teleports the cursor instantly and I don't want that, I want it to be smooth transition or something like that.

Comment: Interpolate the position over time.

Comment: 5 position updates per second is something you can see.  Do it at least 4 times faster and it will look smooth.

Comment: Maybe you want to use `MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE | MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE`  rather than `MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE`. Read the "Remarks" section of the [Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646260(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Michael i tried that it changes the cursor position to 0,0

Comment: *only* changing `sleep(200)` to `sleep(50)` will speed up your movement by 4 times. You will probably want 4 times more elements in `xaxis` and `yaxis`, the new ones in between the current ones

Comment: The formula for linear slope is `y = mx + b`. So rather than move the cursor to the next position, you'll want to move the cursor to the next position over a period of time along the slope between the current cursor position and the next position in your array. You can calculate the `x` and `y` positions by solving for `x` and `y` in the `y = mx + b` formula.

Comment: @Icemanind that's how i want to do it but i don't know how!

Comment: @zero298 how..?

Comment: You can't move the mouse.  You can only move the cursor on the display.

Comment: If you use `Sleep()` in your loop I highly doubt you'll get a smooth result.

Comment: @stark: Bogus. You *can* move the mouse, using `mouse_event` or `SendInput`. If you want to change the cursor position, that's done through a call to `SetCursorPos`. Unclear, why anyone would upvote a comment, that's simply wrong.

Comment: @IInspectable  You must have a better model of mouse.  Mine has no motors.

Comment: @stark: Chances are, that I do. Besides that, I was commenting on your flawed understanding, of how the mouse is abstracted by the system. There is a mouse cursor, and there is internal state, that represents the physical mouse state. I have provided API calls to update either.

Comment: @IInspectable I'm using mouse_event to control the mouse x axis and y axis in game and when the user hold left click the mouse will smoothly move with my entered x axis and y axis.

Answer (score 2):

From what it looks like, you are trying to move across a path of points in a smooth manner.

If so, then you are going to have to interpolate along that path via time.

Essentially, the idea is that you first obtain the total length of the path. Then as you are updating time you obtain a total distance via the total duration and the elapsed amount of time. Finally, you find the two points where the obtained distance is somewhere in the middle. Then you simply interpolate along those two points to get a relatively accurate point.

With this class you can pass the points for the path and a a duration to specify how long you would like to be moving along the path for. Then you would simply update it via time intervals.

**Mover.h**

```
#include <chrono>
#include <vector>

#ifndef MOVER_H
#define MOVER_H


struct Point {
    int x, y;
    Point(int x_, int y_)
        : x(x_), y(y_) {

    }

    Point() : Point(0, 0) {

    }
};


class Mover {
public:
    struct PointData {
        float total;
        float distance;
        Point p1;
        Point p2;

        PointData()
            : total(0.f),
            distance(0.f) {

        }

        PointData(float total, float distance, Point p1, Point p2)
            : total(total),
            distance(distance),
            p1(p1),
            p2(p2) {

        }
    };
    using TimePoint = std::chrono::microseconds;
private:
    std::vector<Point> m_points;
    std::vector<PointData> m_distances;
    TimePoint m_duration;
    TimePoint m_elapsed;
    float m_length;
public:
    Mover(std::initializer_list<Point> points, TimePoint duration = std::chrono::microseconds(2000000));

    template<typename iter_t>
    Mover(iter_t begin, iter_t end, TimePoint duration = std::chrono::microseconds(2000000))
        : m_points(begin, end),
        m_duration(duration),
        m_elapsed(std::chrono::milliseconds(0)) {
        updateLength();
    }

    Mover(const Mover&) = default;

    Mover& operator=(const Mover&) = default;

    Point update(TimePoint delta);

    bool isComplete() const;

    void setDuration(TimePoint duration);

    TimePoint getDuration() const;

    TimePoint getElapsed() const;
private:
    void updateLength();
};


#endif // MOVER_H
```

**Mover.cpp**

```
#include "Mover.h"
#include <algorithm>
#include <cmath>


Mover::Mover(std::initializer_list<Point> points, TimePoint duration)
    : Mover(points.begin(), points.end(), duration)
{
}

Point Mover::update(TimePoint delta)
{
    const auto comparison = [](float left, const PointData& right) {
        return left < right.total;
    };
    m_elapsed = std::min(m_elapsed + delta, m_duration);
    const float length = (static_cast<float>(m_elapsed.count()) / static_cast<float>(m_duration.count())) * m_length;
    auto& data = *std::prev(std::upper_bound(m_distances.begin(), m_distances.end(), length, comparison));
    const float percent = (length - data.total) / data.distance;
    Point point(data.p1.x + percent * (data.p2.x - data.p1.x), data.p1.y + percent * (data.p2.y - data.p1.y));
    return point;
}

bool Mover::isComplete() const
{
    return m_duration == m_elapsed;
}

void Mover::setDuration(TimePoint duration)
{
    m_duration = duration;
}

Mover::TimePoint Mover::getDuration() const
{
    return m_duration;
}

Mover::TimePoint Mover::getElapsed() const
{
    return  m_elapsed;
}

void Mover::updateLength()
{
    auto distance = [](float x1, float y1, float x2, float y2) -> float{
        return std::sqrt(((x1 - x2) * (x1 - x2) + (y1 - y2) * (y1 - y2)));
    };
    float length = 0.f;
    for (std::size_t index = 0; (index + 1) < m_points.size(); ++index) {
        const float dist = distance(m_points[index].x, m_points[index].y, m_points[index + 1].x, m_points[index + 1].y);
        m_distances.emplace_back(length, dist, m_points[index], m_points[index + 1]);
        length += dist;
    }
    m_length = length;  
}
```

**Example**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Mover.h"
int main() {
    std::vector<Point> points{ { 0, 0 }, { 100, 100 } };

    Mover move(points.begin(), points.end());
    auto t1 = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    while (!move.isComplete()) {
        auto t2 = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
        auto point = move.update(std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(t2 - t1));
        std::cout << point.x << ' ' << point.y;
        t1 = t2;
    }
}
```

It's worth mentioning that in order to use this you are going to have to keep track of the time in order to update the mover. So it's probably worth implementing a Clock class or something to keep track of the time for you.

Also, if you want to move along the path relative to the current cursor position, then you would have to simply add the cursor position to the active path point.

Comment: I used this sample but i don't know how to use its function for my code...

Comment: If you do not understand mouse input in Windows, you are destined to fail. This solution ignores an important detail about mouse input. See [Why do I get spurious WM_MOUSEMOVE messages?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20031001-00/?p=42343) for details.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is very late but I might as well answer it.
while doing golang I used this library called robot.go and over there they have a function that does the smooth input. So if you want you can use that as a reference.
https://github.com/go-vgo/robotgo/blob/master/mouse/mouse_c.h

Answer (score -2):

looking at your code your mouse will jump  pixels every 200 ms.

```
    while (LeftMouseDown)
    {
        POINT cursorPos;
        GetCursorPos(&cursorPos);
        //X Axis And Y Axis is DWORD Array
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
           mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE, (xaxis[icount]-cursorPos.x)/20, (yaxis[icount]-cursorPos.y)/20, 0, 0);
           iCount++;
           Sleep(10);
        }
    }
```

Comment: This answer looks totally wrong to me. Read the question again and then re your answer again.

Comment: i didn't get it

Comment: If you need to guess, you are the wrong person to submit an answer. Likewise, if you cannot explain, what the issue is, or how your solution addresses it, you are the wrong person to submit an answer.